# Show $\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty }(-a_{n}) = -\liminf_{n\rightarrow \infty }(a_{n})$

Tags: real-analysis

Show $\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty }(-a_{n}) = -\liminf_{n\rightarrow \infty }(a_{n})$ for a sequence $(a_{n})\subset\mathbb{R}$

Attempt:
$\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty }(-a_{n}) = \inf_{n\geq1 }(\sup\begin{Bmatrix}
-a_{n},-(a_{n+1}),...
\end{Bmatrix} )$

Now using the fact $-\sup(-A) = \inf(A)$ where $A\subset\mathbb{R}$

$= \inf_{n\geq1 }(-\inf\begin{Bmatrix}
a_{n},a_{n+1},...
\end{Bmatrix} )$
$= -\inf_{n\geq1 }(\inf\begin{Bmatrix}
a_{n},a_{n+1},...
\end{Bmatrix} )$

I would like to show $-\inf_{n\geq1 }(\inf\begin{Bmatrix}
a_{n},a_{n+1},...
\end{Bmatrix} )= -\sup_{n\geq1 }(\inf\begin{Bmatrix}
a_{n},a_{n+1},...
\end{Bmatrix} ) = -\liminf_{n\rightarrow \infty }(a_{n})$
but im not sure the previous inf(-inf) = -inf(inf) step is even correct. 
Still trying to wrap my head around this concept!

Comment: It's useful to write down the sets as precise as possible (instead of implicitly). Sometimes it's unclear (at least for me) what your given set look like.

Answer (score 0):

We can rewrite $\limsup$ as
\begin{align*}
\limsup_{n \to \infty} (-a_n) &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \sup_{k > n} (-a_k) \\
&\stackrel{(*)}{=} \lim_{n \to \infty} -\inf_{k > n} (a_k) \\
&= -\lim_{n \to \infty} \inf_{k > n} (a_k) \\
&= -\liminf_{n \to \infty} (a_n) \\
\end{align*}
where $(*)$ follows from the fact that $\sup (-A) = -\inf (A)$, as you've stated.

Comment: Thank you, I was overthinking this one.